# Magento 2 : Bundle product can't add products with custom options

Tags: magento2, bundle

A binding product is created, but a simple product with custom options can't be added.

Comment: Please help me ,thanks.

Comment: Do your simple products have required options? I believe that Magento filters these out of the products that can be added to bundles.